# Object.create() says parameter is not an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

**Description**

In my program I am reading a JSON file, parsing it into an object and then I try to "cast" it into an object of the class `ProjectFile` using `Object.create()`.

**Code**

```
let tmpFileContent = fs.readFileSync(tmpPath, {encoding: 'utf-8'});
let tmpObject = JSON.parse(tmpFileContent);
console.log(tmpObject);
fileList[fileList.length] = Object.create(ProjectFile, tmpObject);
```

**Log**

[image: log]

**Question**

When I output `tmpObject` using `console.log(tmpObject);` it says that it is an object in the log. In the line after that I try to use it as object which should be casted into an object of the class ProjectFile but it displays the error message that it is not an object. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit: ProjectFile class**

```
class ProjectFile {
  constructor(p_name, p_path, p_type, p_thumnailPath) {
    this.name = p_name;
    this.path = p_path;
    this.thumnailPath = p_thumnailPath;
  }
}
```

**Edit 2: Working code**

```
let tmpFileContent = fs.readFileSync(tmpPath, {encoding: 'utf-8'});
          let tmpObject = JSON.parse(tmpFileContent);
          console.log(tmpObject);
          fileList[fileList.length] = Object.create(ProjectFile, {
            name: {
              value: tmpObject.name,
              writable: true,
              enumerable: true,
              configurable: true
            },
            path: {
              value: tmpObject.path,
              writable: true,
              enumerable: true,
              configurable: true
            },
            thumnailPath: {
              value: tmpObject.thumnailPath,
              writable: true,
              enumerable: true,
              configurable: true
            }
          });
```

Comment: The type of `ProjectFile` is "function".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object.create function gets the prototype as the first parameter and property descriptors as the second parameter.

Your second parameter has wrong type. You need to pass an object, which contains objects with property attributes which are `configurable`, `writable`, `enumerable` and the `value` for it.

See the example. In the second case when I pass an parameter which does not apply for the desired shape, it gives me the same error.

```js
const pr = { name: 'Name' };
const successChild = Object.create( pr, {
  surname: {
    value: 'Surname',
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  }
});

console.log(successChild);

const errorChild = Object.create( pr, {
  name: 'Error Name',
  surname: 'Error Surname'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I have added the ProjectFile class. The JSON I parse is of an object that extends the ProjectFile class but the files I read will be from different objects (which all extend the ProjectFile class). Is it an problem that it contains more variables than the ProjectFile class?

Comment: The problem is that your second parameter must be descriptor of properties, not an arbitrary object. What you actually want to do with this two objects?

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understood it now. I added the now working code but it seems like the `Object.create()` function was not really what I was looking for. I wanted to cast it to make sure that every read object is of the class ProjectFile and has its variables and can do its methods but it should also be able to contain more than these variables. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: As I understood you need an object with the composed properties of this two. You can do this via `Object.assign({}, ProjectFile, tmpObject)`. Or if you want the object to be prototype inherited from the `ProjectFile`, remove that from the above function and after it use `Object.setPrototypeOf` function

Comment: Thanks! That looks like what I was trying to do, I will try that.

Comment: See the descriptions of the functions in the documentation